# Is source code uploaded to Azure DevOps repos encrypted at rest?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Does anyone one know if source code in Azure DevOps is encrypted at rest? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Azure DevOps documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper?view=azure-devops), it seems that it is:

• For data stored in Azure SQL databases, Azure DevOps adopted Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) to protect against the threat of malicious activity by performing real-time encryption of the database, associated backups, and transaction log files at rest.

• Azure Blob Storage connections are encrypted to protect your data in transit. **To protect data at rest stored in our Azure Blob Storage, we have adopted Azure Storage Service Encryption (SSE)**.

Azure Storage allows at-rest encryption with a customer-managed key too:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption-customer-managed-keys?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fqueues%2ftoc.json